# How to change icon by onChange in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I try to set onChange to change icon.
But it does not work.

front-end: React
css: semantic-ui-react

```js
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      icon: 'image',
    };
    this.changeIcon = this.changeIcon.bind(this);
  }

  changeIcon() {
    this.setState({icon: 'delete'});
    console.log(this.state.icon);
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <List>
            {(this.state.files || []).map((file, i) => {
              return (
                <List.Item
                  //icon="image"
                  icon={`${this.state.icon}`}
                  content={file.name}
                  onClick={this.handleRemove}
                  onChange={this.changeIcon}
                />
              );
            })}
          </List>
    );
  }
```

Full code is here:
https://github.com/jpskgc/article/blob/master/client/src/components/Detail.tsx

I expect the onChange works to change icon from image to delete.
But the actual does not.
[image]

Comment: {`${this.state.icon}`}, try {this.state.icon} ?

Comment: both ways are exactly the same thing

Comment: I haven't used semantic-ui-react but does List.Item have onChange prop ? https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/list/

Answer (score 0):

As they say in the documentation [changing state might be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

Perhaps instead of passing an object to setState you could try to pass a function?

Hope it helps :)